# How do I fix implementation error in JAVA VS code, "must implement the inherited abstract class"

Tags: java, class, generics, arraylist, interface

I am currently learning interfaces, classes and generics.

My current assignment is to create a class which mimics "ArrayLists" in Java. (probably java 7)

[this is the interface](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse143/03au/coursework/demos/SimpleArrayList/doc/index.html)

I have created a class: `public class StudentArrayList implements SimpleArrayList<E> {`
but I am getting this error: [I am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4dSY.png)

Error: `The type StudentArrayList must implement the inherited abstract method SimpleArrayList<E>.set(int, E)Java(67109264)`

I have already implemented all the function signatures in the class, but it is still me asking to implement again and again.
How do I fix this issue? please let me know.
Thanks!

**StudentArrayList.java:**

```
public class StudentArrayList implements SimpleArrayList<E> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Success");
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(E o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public E[] toArray() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(E e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void remove(E o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(SimpleArrayList<E> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(SimpleArrayList<E> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, SimpleArrayList<E> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(SimpleArrayList<E> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(SimpleArrayList<E> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int index, E element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, E element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void remove(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(E o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(E o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleArrayList subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}`
```

Comment: MS Visual Code is great ... but for Java, I'd STRONGLY recommend an IDE like Eclipse (my preference), NetBeans or IntelliJ.

Comment: IntellJ doesn't work on my computer for some reason, I have to submit this assignment very soon, so I cannot spend time on installing/fixing IntellJ

Comment: Use a text editor then. Sublime Text, Atom, Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to write a generic class that implements an generic interface.  The problem is that you have not actually declared the class as generic.  And the compiler therefore things that `E` is a class name.

The declaration:

```
public class StudentArrayList implements SimpleArrayList<E> {
```

should be:

```
public class StudentArrayList<E> implements SimpleArrayList<E> {
```

The `<E>` after `StudentArrayList` declares `E` as a type parameter of `StudentArrayList`.

The compilation errors were probably a result of the compiler thinking that `E` was a class name (rather than a type parameter) and not being to find any definition for it.